# How to make keyboard stay fixed to UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, keyboard

I'm using [JASidePanels](https://github.com/gotosleep/JASidePanels) to have a slideout-menu in my app. One of the views I have has a always-visible keyboard. My problem is that, when in this keyboard-fixed view, and I show the menu, the keyboard stays at the center of my window instead of following the view i hid to show the menu. I understand why this is, but I would like to tweak it so it follows the view im swiping to the right, instead of staying in the middle.

TL;DR how can I stick a keyboard fixed to a UIView, instead of staying in front of whole app window

Comment: I had this problem too. Better use https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController

Comment: Fix but it'll cost you a day: Create your own keyboard view.

Comment: @LordZsolt It might actually not be that bad.. I'm just using the numeric decimal pad, its just 12 keys

Comment: Oh then that's pretty easy. Only like 3 methods (1 for numbers, 1 for * and one for #). Then you can set the tags for the number buttons equal to their value (button0.tag = 0, button1.tag = 1), and determine which button was tapped via sender.tag).

Comment: I'll have to consider switching to MMDrawer as danipralea suggested, but i'm going to try making my own keyboard first.